# How to pass data into function, inside HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I fixed the problem by calling a function, that graps the id of the table row it is placed in :)

I have this piece of code sorting some different stuff into a table, that works fine. The problem is to pass data into a function called inside HTML tags, like so:
[See reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilVVW.png)

```
$.when(document, getTournamentsData()).done(function(){
var output = "";
$.each(tournamentsData, function(key, data){
        output += "<tr class='data_row "+data.isOpen+"' id='"+data._id+"'>";
        output += "<td>" + (key+1) + "</td>";
        output += "<td><b>" + data.name + "</b></td>";
        output += "<td>Start: " + data.begintime + "<br>Slut: " + data.endtime + "</td>";
        output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se beskrivelse' onclick='showTourDescription(data.description)'/></td>";
        output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se billede' onclick='showPic(data.image)'/></td>";
        output += "<td>Max antal: "+ data.max_teams +"<br>Tilmeldte: "+ data.teams.length +"</td><br>";
        output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se deltagere' onclick='showMembers(data.teams)'/></td>";
        output += "<td>" + prizes(data.prices) + "</td>";                                                                                               
        output += "</tr>";
});
output += "";
$('#data_insert').append(output);
```

});

All I do in the function is to console the data, and I get error "data is not defined"

This is the full script https://github.com/Jakobtottrup/OptekSemester2/blob/master/Web/public/js/tournaments_admin.js

Comment: have you echoed the tournamentsData to the console, to make sure there's something there? If data is not defined, it may be that tournamentsData is also either null or not defined...

Comment: Yes, alle the other "data" variables works fine. It's just those variables inside the function calls

Comment: Are you forgetting to pass tournamentsData into the .done callback function as a parameter? I don't see it defined anywhere...

Comment: I believe defined as an global variable. I updated my question with a link to the script file

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Looks like you are passing data as string. See if that works

```
$.each(tournamentsData, function(data) {
```

```js
onclick='showTourDescription(" + data.description + ")
```

Comment: Thanks, but the data is getting pass in properly, as all the other variables (fx "data.isOpen") works fine - only those inside the function call does not work

Comment: Help me understand. getTournamentsData() is returning some array data, and for each item you are looping to construct the html string. correct? Did you try my code?

Comment: What's happening is you're passing data.description (the string 'data.description') rather than it's value. End the quoted string, concatenate the value, and restart the quoted string after.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I tired your solution, but then I don't get any data through? oO

Comment: Have you an example you're working with? whether here or a fiddle.

Comment: Give me a moment, i'll try setting up jsfiddle for an example

Comment: I can't really get jsfiddle to work, as this project is build on nodejs, so there is too many file references :/

Comment: Dis you try with " + data.description + ". You are passing part of string as of now, and therefore the function will be getting string "data.description" rather data.description (property of data)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// list tournaments
$.when(document, getTournamentsData()).done(function(){
    var output = "";
    $.each(tournamentsData, function(key, data){
            output += "<tr class='data_row "+convertBoolean(data.isOpen)+"' id='"+data._id+"'>";
            output += "<td>" + (key+1) + "</td>";                                                                                                           // index
            output += "<td><b>" + data.name + "</b></td>";                                                                                                  // navn
            output += "<td>Start: " + data.begintime + "<br>Slut: " + data.endtime + "</td>";                                                               // start/slut
            output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se beskrivelse' onclick='showTourDescription("+data.description+")'/></td>";     // beskrivelse TODO
            output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se billede' onclick='showPic("+data.description+")'/></td>";                     // billede
            output += "<td>Max antal: "+ data.max_teams +"<br>Tilmeldte: "+ data.teams.length +"</td><br>";                                                 // hold
            output += "<td><input class='btn btn-primary' type='button' value='Se deltagere' onclick='showMembers("+data.teams"+)'/></td>";                     // medlemmer
            output += "<td>" + prizes(data.prices) + "</td>";                                                                                               // præmier
            output += "</tr>";
    });
```

I've taken your code, and as you've done in the HTML strings themselves, concatenated in the event handlers too. Should be all you need to do.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get "unexpected string" on >onclick='showMembers("+data.teams"+)'<

Comment: Could that be because you've made it "+data.teams"+ rather than "+data.teams+" ? note the last plus-quote

Comment: Do you see what I mean, @Christian?

Comment: Yes, I see. I get this "missing )", but I can't find where it is missing https://i.gyazo.com/fbeaf80b7732fd86c4327fbe16dc0944.png

Comment: it is an unexpected string, because the plus sign is on the wrong side of the quote mark.